# Edittext not getting focus in listview adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

IDK but i am continuously getting this issue **To make request focus on EditText when Keyboard next button is pressed in adapter**.

I have set the `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` in my `adapter` layout. When i am on first item of 'ListView' then its is working fine.

But when i press `next` from the keyboard. It goes to next position of `EditText` in  `ListView` which is perfect but the `EditText` is not getting the `requestFocus()` and same problem with other next item.

I tired all the solutions i found out in **stackoverflow** . But i think i am unable to find out the best solution.

Could you please help me out.

Any help will deeply appriciated. Please check the screenshots below.

[image: EditText is not getting requestFocus()]

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/21961346/1320616

Comment: @ankitaggarwal i tried out the solution but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will helps you :-

```
txtUserid.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
          if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
               (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
          {
                // Perform action on Enter key press
                txtone.clearFocus();
                txtsecond.requestFocus();
                return true;
          }
          return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: My EditText is in adapter, and i am inflating the layout for the number of items. i tried out this also but its not working. Its only a one EditText which is used for number of items. 

The edittext is equal to the data coming from the server.

Comment: OK let me try more on it. thank you for support and welcome here. we are all for you . :)

Comment: Yes please help me out of this because i am stuck here for too many days.